# String placeholder unsupported format character

Tags: python

I want to generate latex documents using python. So I create a template and use string placeholder to alter value.

> template = r'''
>
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm]{geometry}
>   \usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish',
>   'danish', etc. \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{txfonts}
>   \usepackage{mathdots} \usepackage{pifont} \usepackage{wasysym}
>   \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{tabularx,pbox}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \noindent Form A
>
> \noindent  \newline
>
> \noindent \textbf{Expansion of Hong Kong International Airport into a
>   Three-Runway System}
>
> \noindent Marine Travel Routes and Management Plan for High Speed
>   Ferries of SkyPier
>
> \noindent \textbf{\underbar{}}
>
> \noindent \textbf{\underbar{Environmental Audit Checking Record}}
>
> \noindent
>
> \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}  \hline  Reference Plan: & Marine
>   Travel Routes and Management Plan for High Speed Ferries of SkyPier
>   (EP Condition 2.10) \ \hline Monitoring Data: & Ferry movement data
>   collected in the period between  \textbf{\underbar{"%(start_date)s" to
>   "%(end_date)s"}} \ \hline Information and Data Checked:  &\CheckedBox
>   Automatic Identification System (AIS) Data \newline \CheckedBox Daily
>   SkyPier HSF movements \newline \CheckedBox Record of potential
>   deviations \newline \CheckedBox Response provided by the ferry
>   operators\ \hline Comments and Observations: & The deviation of
>   implementation of SkyPier HSF plan was checked. Eight notices were
>   issued by AAHK to ferry operators related to potential speeding across
>   the SCZ, not travelling through the gate access points and \ \hline
>
> \end{tabularx}
>
> \noindent  \newline \newline \newline \newline \newline \newline
>
> \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|} \hline  & ET Leader \newline
>   ET's Representative & IEC \newline IEC's Representative & PM \newline
>   PM's Representative\ \hline Signature&&&\ \hline Name & Terence
>   Kong&&\ \hline \end{tabularx}
>
> \noindent
>
> \end{document}
>
> '''

However, when I try to run

```
page = template % {'start_date' : 'a', 'end_date' : 'b' }
```

It returns

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 120
```

Comment: cannot reproduce, works fine in my 3.4 environment.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on py 3.6 and on 2.7 too

Comment: the actual template is longer. Coz Stakeoverflow said there is too many codes, so I cut some.

Comment: please check the edited post.

Comment: I got the answer. the %%% in the package lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `%%%` in the line

```
\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm]{geometry} \usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc. \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{txfonts} \usepackage{mathdots} \usepackage{pifont} \usepackage{wasysym} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{tabularx,pbox}
```

When using `%` to format strings, you can write an *actual* `%` by escaping it as `%%`, so `%%%` is interpreted as one *actual* `%` followed by another `%` used as a placeholder, with the following `"'"` being interpreted as the (unrecognized) format character.

Just replace the `%%%` by an even number of `%`, e.g. `%%%%%%` if you want to have exactly 3 `%` in the resulting Latex code, but any other even number will work, too.